# LINQ - Multiple left joins with nullable values

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to translate the following SQL query to LINQ, but I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

SQL QUERY

```
SELECT a.ID_TARGET,a.TARGET_NAME, b.OBJECTIVE_NAME, c.PERSPECTIVE_NAME FROM IL_OPR_MTR_TGT AS a
LEFT JOIN IL_OPR_MTR_OBJ b ON a.TARGET_OBJECTIVE_ID = b.ID_OBJECTIVE
LEFT JOIN IL_OPR_MTR_PRSPCT c ON b.OBJECTIVE_PERSPECT_ID = c.PERSPECTIVE_ID;
```

SQL OUTPUT

```
ID_TARGET |TARGET_NAME  |OBJECTIVE_NAME |PERSPECTIVE_NAME
----------|-------------|---------------|----------------
    7     |TGT_01       |   TST02       |PERSPECTIVE_01
    8     |TGT01        |   TST02       |PERSPECTIVE_01
    9     |TARGET_02    |   TST02       |PERSPECTIVE_01
    10    |TARGET003AA  |   (null)      |(null)
```

LINQ QUERY

```
var data = (from a in allTargets
join b in allObjectives on a.TARGET_OBJECTIVE_ID equals b.ID_OBJECTIVE into partial1
from b in partial1.DefaultIfEmpty()
join c in allPerspectives on b.OBJECTIVE_PERSPECT_ID equals c.PERSPECTIVE_ID into partial2
from c in partial2.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    ID_TARGET = a.ID_TARGET,
    TARGET_NAME = a.TARGET_NAME,
    OBJECTIVE_NAME = b != null ? b.OBJECTIVE_NAME : "",
    PERSPECTIVE_NAME = c != null ? c.PERSPECTIVE_NAME : ""
}).ToList();
```

I guess the problem is here, since i'm trying to join two NULL values, but I cant figure out how to fix that...

```
join c in allPerspectives on b.OBJECTIVE_PERSPECT_ID equals c.PERSPECTIVE_ID into partial2
from c in partial2.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: I think that the problem it is you are referencing your data by "a" and "b" names, while you have all of your data in the last partial2 Enumerable collection, so you should reference them by "c" alias name of your item collection..

Comment: What is `allTargets`? Looking at the exception, seems to be some memory collection? If it was `IQueryable` (LINQ to Entities), your query would work w/o any problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to null-check `b` in your query, something like:

```
join c in allPerspectives on (b == null ? "no-value" : b.OBJECTIVE_PERSPECT_ID) equals c.PERSPECTIVE_ID
```

Comment: Thank you very much, leetibbett! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to instantiate a new object instead of using the `default` which is `null`. The syntax is something like `partial1.DefaultIfEmpty(new AllObjective())`